# How do drift chambers work?

Tags: radiation, particle-detectors

In a drift chamber we know only the distance from the wire by knowing the drift velocity, so how is it possible to reconstruct a 3D image of the particle trajectory?

Answer (score 1):

The location along the wire where the charge is deposited  will affect the time taken for that charge to be collected (i.e. read-out) from the wire, and also the pulse shape of the collected charge. After calibrating your detector, and combining this information with the other wires, and with precise timing, you can reconstruct where along each wire the particle traversed, and hence get 3D information.